# Все аудео дорожки MediaElement - mp4

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Может кто подсказать? Как в WPF заставить `MediaElement` воспроизводить все аудио дорожки из видео. 
Я открываю видео (кусок моего геймплея) но из звука только игра но в самом файле 3 источника звука (микро, дискорд, игра), формат `mp4`

На деле проблема не критичная ибо пишу обрезалку видео для себя и это единственная не решенная проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе полазив и почитав я нашел ответ на собственный вопрос. И ответ очень прост!
Мое видео было записано с помощью ShadowPlay от NVidia и в настройках было включено, разбивать источники звука на разные дорожки. И все они были сложены в mp4 файл как в контейнер. Но а MediaElement из WPF не знает как правильно прочесть эти дорожки (хотя скорее просто их не видит). По хорошему стоило переписать плеер но я не стал не чего менять. Так же можно собирать дорожки в одну при открытии файла но в этом нет смысла. Так-же эта проблема существует в стандартом плеере Windows 10.

*Надеюсь кому-то поможет, хотя подобная тема уже есть на русском Stack Overflow.*